# Can’t attach USB device

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox, raspberry-pi, virtual-machine

I just recently installed Virtual Box on my host laptop (MacBook) and I am trying to use Raspberry Pi OS (Debian). However, I am having a hard time with the VirtualBox detecting the USB Device in the Virtual Machine.

I tried installing new versions of both the Virtual box and the extension pack. It still does not work. I have also enabled the USB Controller Option but it still does not work.

Can someone please assist with this issue and explaining why this might be occurring?

Comment: There's a simple way to attach USB devices in Virtualbox, it's in the menus. But why exactly are you using Virtualbox and installing Raspberry Pi OS as a VM? Shouldn't you be downloading and installing the **Raspberry Pi Imager** for MacOS and then run it in order to install the OS in the USB stick?

Comment: Hello @ChanganAuto, Sorry about the confusion. I did install the Debian on usb stick through the Pi Imager. I was trying to get another usb device to use in VM which is not detecting.

Comment: are you trying to install the "Raspberry Pi Desktop" that is "compatible with MAC and PC" to run the Raspberry Pi "flavoured" Debian on a desktop machine? If not, then you're doing it wrong

Comment: Hello @JaromandaX, If you are referring to installing a Raspberry Pi Desktop for Mac Version. I did not do that. I am trying to use that on Virtual Box.

Comment: yes, but which version, Pi for Arm (i.e. physical Pi boards), or Pi Desktop for Mac and PC